# Display real progress of loading WPF DataGrid instead of .IsIndeterminate

Tags: c#, datagrid, progress-bar

I have managed to get ProgressBar into my WPF form. However  my current skill is stuck on using:

```
ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;

DataGrid1.ItemsSource = await GetDataAsync();

ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
```

Any professional ready to describe how to get ProgressBar to display actual loading progress?

Here is my full code:

```
    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;

            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = await GetDataAsync();

            ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private Task<DataView> GetDataAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {

            string connectionStringDE = "Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=DE875;dbq=@DEDBFS;Uid=DEUsername;Pwd=DEPassword;";
            string queryStringDE = "select NRO,NAME,NAMEA,NAMEB,ADDRESS,POSTA,POSTN,POSTADR,COMPANYN,COUNTRY,ID,ACTIVE from COMPANY";
            string connectionStringFR = "Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=FR875;dbq=@FRDBFS;Uid=FRUsername;Pwd=FRPassword;";
            string queryStringFR = "select NRO,NAME,NAMEA,NAMEB,ADDRESS,POSTA,POSTN,POSTADR,COMPANYN,COUNTRY,ID,ACTIVE from COMPANY";

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("COMPANY");
            // using-statement will cleanly close and dispose unmanaged resources i.e. IDisposable instances
            using (OdbcConnection dbConnectionDE = new OdbcConnection(connectionStringDE))
            {
                dbConnectionDE.Open();
                OdbcDataAdapter dadapterDE = new OdbcDataAdapter();
                dadapterDE.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(queryStringDE, dbConnectionDE);

                dadapterDE.Fill(dataTable);

            }
            using (OdbcConnection dbConnectionFR = new OdbcConnection(connectionStringFR))
            {
                dbConnectionFR.Open();
                OdbcDataAdapter dadapterFR = new OdbcDataAdapter();
                dadapterFR.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(queryStringFR, dbConnectionFR);

                var newTable = new DataTable("COMPANY");
                dadapterFR.Fill(newTable);

                dataTable.Merge(newTable);

            }

            return dataTable.DefaultView;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't display the actual process unless you know it and you don't unless the API that you are using actually reports the current progress to you.

The `OdbcCommand` API doesn't so you should stick to using indeterminate progress bars.